# "Кто это принесла?" — можно так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, род

Можно так спросить в том случае, если помнишь, что это принесла женщина, но не можешь вспомнить, какая именно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При согласовании  глаголов с вопросительным местоимением КТО употребляется муж. род единственного числа.

Для согласования с женским родом употребляется дополнительно местоимение ТАКАЯ:Кто такая принесла мне это?

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Действительно, *кто такая* — не сообразил даже.

Answer (score 2):

**Нет**, так говорить нельзя.

Дело в том, что с местоимением-подлежащим КТО  **глагол-сказуемое употребляется в форме мужского рода единственного числа.**

Правильно: ***Кто это принёс?***

Comment: *Кто **были** эти люди, сказавшие про единственное число?*, *Кто **была** это дама*? Замена на кем роли особой не играет. "Кем" - это ковенный падеж от "кто".

Comment: Кто были эти люди? Здесь БЫЛИ относится к подлежащему люди, а КТО - именная часть сказуемого - БЫЛИ КТО. Тут, на мой взгляд, другой случай. То же самое можно сказать о втором примере.А у нас КТО - подлежащее.

Comment: Да, конечно. Я-то понимаю. (Хотя тут можно спорить, грамматика не столь однозначна). А вот вопрошающему наверняка придет в голову что-то подобное. Вы же сказали не "согласуется", а "употребляется" - и про подлежащие ничего не добавили. Людмила точнее в формулировке.

Comment: Спасибо, я согласна. Исправлю чуть-чуть... Добавлю слова "подлежащее" и "сказуемое".

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина!

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что подобным образом можно только *переспросить*, не расслышав имя женщины и повторив произнесённый собеседником глагол:

> -Это принесла Гюльчатай.
>
> -Кто принесла?

Comment: Чуть было не минуснул, а потом подумал, что ведь правда, можно такое услышать. ))) Только вот что вы думаете о нормативности такого употребления?

Comment: «Это принесла Гюльчатай.» «Кто — принесла?»

Comment: Спасибо, интересная мысль!